# Logarithmic Sobolev growth of time-space-periodic Schrödinger solutions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, schrodinger-operators

Consider the following Schrödinger equation
$$i\partial_t \psi (t,x) + \Delta \psi - V(t,x) \psi = 0 \, ,$$
where $x\in \mathbb{T}^d$ and $V(t,\cdot)$ is real, smooth, and periodic (with a diophantine condition on the periodicity wrt $\mathbb{T}^d$).

**Question:** Is there a potential $V$, a dimension $d$, a constant $s>0$, and an initial condition $\psi _0 (x)\in H^s(\mathbb{T}^d)$ such that $\|\psi(t,\cdot)\|_{H^s} \sim \log[2+t]^{C(s)}$ for all $t>0$?

**Background:** 
[Bourgain](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200050644), [Wang](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03605300802537115) and others showed that while this equation preserves the $L^2_x$ norm, under some general conditions, $H^s$ norms with $s>0$ can grow at most logarithmically, e.g., in $d=1$
$$\|\psi(t,\cdot) \|_{H^s_x} \lesssim \log [2+t]^{C s}  \, ,$$
for some $C>0$. A similar statement holds for small potentials in $d=2$.

The best result in ways of a lower bound is in [Bourgain](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200050644) too: for $d=1$ and any $s>0$, there is a sequence of $t_j\to \infty$, $ V_{j}(t,x)$, and  $\psi_{0,j} (x)$ such that $\|\psi_j (t_j, \cdot)\|_{H^s} \sim  \log[2+t_j]^{C(s)}$, where $\psi_j$ is the solution corresponding to the potential $V_j$ with initial condition $\psi_{0,j}$. See remark 1.11 at [Maspero and Robert](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123617300915). Whether such growth is possible for a fixed equation is unclear.